# CSS auto margin on one side

Tags: html, css

I have a small dilemma with a page design. It's best described in image form.

[image]

The top image represents the page as it is now - blue being my nav container and yellow, the page content.

At present, the nav is a full width (split left and right) while content is limited to 1024px wide and simply centered using margin auto.

However, on wide pages this looks odd. So, what I'd like to do is right align the menu items with the right-hand side of the content (as in the lower image). The issue being that I don't know the width of the left/right margin.

I have no doubt that this can be achieved using javascript but given that its fundamental to the page design, I'd rather try and achieve something using CSS.

At present, I'm not even sure this is achievable using CSS alone - anyone done something like this before?

```css
header {
  background: blue;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:0 24px;
  height:64px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
    flex: initial;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  
}
nav {
  flex: 0 0 auth;
  margin-left:40px;
}
ul {
  display:flex;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li > a {
  color:Black;
  padding:0 16px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
main {
  background-color:yellow;
  max-width:1024px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title">This is a really long title that replaces the logo.</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <p>
   This is some content.
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: Make your top bar 1024 max width and center using margin auto. For the site title/logo on the left hand side, use absolute positioning

Comment: simply use container inside nav and make it max-width like below content ... if you provide your code we can better help you

Comment: @Huangism - the logo might not always be a logo - it could be a longer page title or something else. At present I can ensure the left hand box is clipped if necessary (when it meets the right hand box) but I couldn't do that when using absolute positioning.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - please see my reply to Huangism.

Comment: share your code :) me or @Huangism are giving idea based on your screens, to give you a correct thing we need to have your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif - created a starter fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some calculation with `calc()`. The `header` is 100% width and the content is 1024px so inside the `header` you need to add a padding right equal to one margin which is : `(100% - 1024px)/2`

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
header {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: calc((100% - 1024px) / 2);
  height: 64px;
}

.title {
  flex: initial;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav {
  flex: 0 0 auth;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li>a {
  color: Black;
  padding: 0 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

main {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="title">This is a really long title that replaces the logo.</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <p>
    This is some content.
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: You did it - I can also remove the divide by and use 50%/512px so its better supported.

Comment: @JohnOhara well it's mathematic, so play with it as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<header>
  <div class="title">Mysite.co.uk</div>
  <nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <ul>
  </nav>
</header>

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

header nav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin 0 auto;
}

header .title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u0wm4s4k/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonas. The issue is that the logo may not always be a logo - it could be some other text relevant to the page - such as a title. Positioning the left hand container takes it out of the flow so I can't limit its size if needed.

Comment: Check out the Fiddle! :)

Comment: @JohnOhara you can emulate it by fixing a `padding-right` to your logo/text area, the same size as your `Item1 Item2 Item3`, so that text goes to new line. The proper exact size would need getting it in JS, but you can have a decent approximation of it's maximum, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```css
header {
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

nav {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0;  
}

section {
  background: yellow;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Logo
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item1</li>
  </ul>
</header>
<main>
  <section>content</section>
</main>
```